# Autolayout - UILabel shrinks in width after orientation change, cause by another UILabel which is supposed to auto-adjust font size

Tags: ios, autolayout, uilabel

I have 2 `UILabel` side-by-side horizontally using auto-layout as following:

1. **1st-Label** is full-width (like sizeToFit)
2. **2nd-Label** has `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true`

[image]

On launch everything is fine, when returning from landscape to portrait 1st-Label shrinks to zero width.

Constraints are following:

- 1st Label: `H:|-0-[1stLabel]`, `V:[1stLabel]-0-|`
- 2nd Label: `H:[2ndLabel]-0-|`, `V:[2ndLabel]-0-|`
- **Leading/Trailing Relation Constraint:** `H:[1stLabel]-(>=1)-[2ndLabel]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed to set ContentCompressionResistancePriority on 2nd-Label:

```
secondLabel.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultLow, for:.horizontal)
```

Answer (score 1):

set compression resistance priority of label 1 to 1000